# Virtual bridged networking with VLAN, could not ping

Tags: linux, vlan, bridge

I require a virtual network  **with VLAN**  be build between two virtual hosts - which can be (lxc/ vbox -ubuntu or win xp).
I tried with lxc and vbox with Ubuntu and was finding difficult to make it work without vlan, but was successful with vbox with xp.

`vbox-xp1 --- br1 ---------------- br2 ---- vbox-xp2`

The config is:

```
brctl addbr br1;     brctl addbr br2
ifconfig br1 up;     ifconfig br2 up
stp  br1 off;        stp  br2 off

ip link add name br1-br2-l0 type veth peer name br1-br2-l1
sudo brctl addif br1 br1-br2-l0
sudo brctl addif br2 br1-br2-l1
```

vbox - xp 1 and 2  with network ; bridged and br1 and br2 respectively.
The adapter is intel PRO/1000 MT Server and driver installed in guests.

- Configured IPs and two hosts pinged!

VLAN config:

```
ip link add link br1 name br1-2.5 type vlan id 5
brctl addif br2 br1-2.5
```

create vlan 5 in xp 1 and 2 and assign ip address

---

Ping on with this config does not work.
Wireshark trace on interface  br1-br2-l1 / br1-2.5 shows that one ping results in ~240 ping packets and each growing by 4 bytes - first one being correct and  60,

ping does not reach other host as I see mac is not learnt[arp -a].

--
if br1-2.5 is not configured, I see untagged packets in br1-br2-l1/0, but still not reaching other host as mac is not learnt.

if br1-br2-l0/1 is made down, even if br1-2.5 is up, I count not see any packets.

---

I tried with ebtables, but still could not make a correct config to work.

--
If any one here are aware of any configuration, please let me know.
I need to make a network of switches. Seems I have a very long way.

Sorry for a very long question.

Thanks and regards,
vy

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example for VLAN bridging](http://www.stg.net/vlanbridge/).

The example works exactly like I am doing this on real hardware: The vlans are added to the underlying network-devices. After that the network-devices with that vlan-id build up a bridge.

I do not think that this works the other way around.